# kendo ui grid column template not being applied

Tags: telerik, kendo-grid

Followed getting started documentation to setup a basic grid. I added a column template to bold the first column but it is not being applied.  I tried the code in Dojo and it works. Triple checked the syntax, gird is displayed fine with all the data but no bold is applied.

Inspection of the html in chrome shown no style applied to the table data.

This has to be something really simple I'm overlooking...

here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Client</title>
  
<!-- Common Kendo UI CSS for web widgets and widgets for data visualization. -->
    <link href="../css/kendo/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- (Optional) RTL CSS for Kendo UI widgets for the web. Include only in right-to-left applications. -->
    <%--<link href="../css/kendo/kendo.rtl.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />--%>
    <!-- Default Kendo UI theme CSS for web widgets and widgets for data visualization. -->
    <link href="../css/kendo/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- (Optional) Kendo UI Hybrid CSS. Include only if you will use the mobile devices features. -->
    <link href="../css/kendo/kendo.default.mobile.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Kendo UI combined JavaScript -->
    <script src="../js/kendo/kendo.all.min.js"></script>  
  
  <script>

        var people = [
               { firstName: "John",
                   lastName: "Smith",
                   email: "john.smith@telerik.com"
               },
               { firstName: "Jane",
                   lastName: "Smith",
                   email: "jane.smith@telerik.com"
               },
               { firstName: "Josh",
                   lastName: "Davis",
                   email: "josh.davis@telerik.com"
               },
               { firstName: "Cindy",
                   lastName: "Jones",
                   email: "cindy.jones@telerik.com"
               }
         ];


        $("#client_grid").kendoGrid({
            autoBind: false,
            selectable: true,
            columns: [{
                field: "firstName",
                title: "First Name",
                template: "<strong>#: firstName # </strong>"
            },
            {
                field: "lastName",
                title: "Last Name",
            },
            {
                field: "email",
                title: "Email",
            }]
        });


        $("#client_grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: people
        });

                      
    </script>


</head>
<body>

<div id="client_grid" />


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, based on the code you provided, you are initializing the grid twice:

One:

```
$("#client_grid").kendoGrid({
        autoBind: false,
        selectable: true,
        columns: [{
            field: "firstName",
            title: "First Name",
            template: "<strong>#: firstName # </strong>"
        },
        {
            field: "lastName",
            title: "Last Name",
        },
        {
            field: "email",
            title: "Email",
        }]
    });
```

Two:

```
$("#client_grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: people
    });
```

And the second one is blowing away your config of the first(including the template).

Just do this instead:

```
$("#client_grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: people,
        autoBind: false,
        selectable: true,
        columns: [{
            field: "firstName",
            title: "First Name",
            template: "<strong>#: firstName # </strong>"
        },
        {
            field: "lastName",
            title: "Last Name",
        },
        {
            field: "email",
            title: "Email",
        }]
    });
// Because autobind is false, you have to trigger the fetch somehow...
$("#client_grid").getKendoGrid().dataSource.read();
```

Demo: http://dojo.telerik.com/@Stephen/UPuga

Comment: This works (!) but it requires dataSource:  people to be declared in the initialization...my intent to to bind to remote data obtained by an ajax call so datasource is not known in advance. I see that the double initialization is the problem so how can this be setup to work in that case?

Comment: OK, I see the datasource needs a transport construct for remote data access...I was trying to simulate that (incorrectly) with the above code and reinitialized the grid.  thanks!

Comment: There's the setDataSource() method as well: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-setDataSource